# Que parametros usar con la api de uptobox en php

Tags: php, api

En la documentacion de la api esta este codigo para generar un enlace para la subida de archivos.

```
$url = 'https://uptobox.com/api/upload';
$data = [
    'token' => 'USER_TOKEN'
];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $result;
```

Retorna un json

```
{
    "data": {
      "uploadLink": "//www42.uptobox.com/upload?sess_id=RHEgojX9QJygPzh1rMd3",
      "maxUpload": "200 GB"
    },
    "message": "Success",
    "statusCode": 0
}
```

Utilizo la url retornado en el json y hago la peticion

```
$resultt = json_decode($result, true);

$file = 'mi_video.mp4';
$rrr = "https:".$resultt["data"]["uploadLink"];

if (function_exists('curl_file_create'))
{
    $cFile = curl_file_create($file);
}else{
    $cFile = '@' . realpath($file);
}

$post = array('file'=> $cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$rrr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rresult = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($rresult);
```

Pero esto me retorna un `bool(false)`

Muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Link de la doc: https://docs.uptobox.com/?php#retrieve-an-upload-url

Answer (score 0):

La documentación de uptobox parece estar incompleta, tambien me encontre con este problema el dia de hoy y he descubierto el parámetro correcto con el cual enviar los archivos para la subida.

El parámetro correcto es `files`, también sirve `files[]` como array, pero solo puedes enviar un archivo a la vez.

Y este sería un ejemplo de la respuesta que te daría la api de uptobox.

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "name": "photo_2020-07-29_19.jpg",
      "size": 75211,
      "url": "https://uptobox.com/f3m69251kq3fa",
      "deleteUrl": "https://uptobox.com/f3m69251kq3fa?killcode=axelci4mjss"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = 'mi_video.mp4'; => fullpathvideo,
$post = array('file'=> $cFile); => $post = array('files'=> $cFile);
```

Lo siento, no sé su idioma, pero puedo explicarlo con una traducción como esta. Si cambia los lugares anteriores, su problema se solucionará.